# WinForms - ComboBox: Find selected item and set index

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, telerik

I have a ComboBox control of type RadMultiColumnComboBox and I'm trying to search and find a string and then set the selected index programmatically.

Here is my code:

```
        // get reference to drop down:
        RadMultiColumnComboBox myComboBox = this.BaseFieldControl;

        // find and set: 
        string toFind = "SomeValue";
        myComboBox.SelectedIndex = myComboBox .FindExact( toFind );
```

The problem is that the controls FindExact method is returning -1 not matter what string I pass into FindExact.

While the app is running I use the Immediate window to test and enter various strings; no matter what I string I use, it returns -1.

If I inspect myComboBox there are 10 items in the DataSource property.

Here is a representation of the ComboBox - it may help:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can cast datasource to original type and find index from DataSource:

```
var data=(List<YourType)myComboBox.DataSource;
myComboBox.SelectedIndex=data.FindIndex(p=>p.Text=="SomeValue");
```

Comment: p.Text is a example you must replaced with p.(your filed want to search)=="SomeData"

Comment: I'm recieving an exception:

{"Unable to cast object of type 'System.ComponentModel.BindingList`1[ECS.Common.Entities.MyType]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ECS.Common.Entities.MyType]'."}

Comment: I think I need a conversion to List<T>?

Comment: ps here is my updated code sample:

var data = (List<MyType>)myComboBox.DataSource;

myComboBox.SelectedIndex = data.FindIndex(p => p.DisplayValue == "SomeValue");

Comment: if you use a databindingsource in line 1 replace this: var data=(List<YourType)databindingsource.DataSource

Comment: I'm not sure where I can find DataBindingSource - I do have a DataBindings property:

var data = (List<MyType>)myComboBox.DataBindings;

but I also receive an error with this saying Cannot convert type 'System.Windows.Forms.ControlBindingsCollection' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<MyType>'

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5114/discussion-between-shawn-and-redhat)